# `docker-compose up --build` yields ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm converting a working django application to run in Docker containers.

```
#Dockerfile

FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3 -q install -r requirements.txt
RUN ls $(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;print(get_python_lib())")
CMD python manage.py runserver
```

the penultimate line prints out my `site-packages` and shows `django` as one of the installed modules. adding `RUN pip3 freeze` shows `Django==1.11.4` which is what I'd expect.

Given this, I can't explain why i'm getting the `ImportError` :

```
api_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1         |   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
api_1         |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
api_1         | ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Also note that there is no `virtualenv` in play here at all. I did read all the other Qs with this error text, and that ain't my problem.

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: Can you add your requirements.txt?

Comment: no, that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. By setting that in the `Dockerfile`'s `.env` file to `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/:/code/`, the container is able to locate the module

Answer (score 0):

With your Dockerfile and a file named manage.py containing

```
import django;print('lol')
```

I get the output "lol" when I run the below

```
docker build . --tag a-django-app
docker run a-django-app
```

So it seems there's nothing wrong with your Dockerfile. However, I don't think docker has an `up` command. Are you referring to docker-compose? In that case you probably need to provide more information. I'm not sure if Stackoverflow is the best forum for this question though.